# How to remove black stripes on the sides

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible in Unity to stretch the image from the camera to the full screen (remove black stripes on the sides) 
 without changing camera size?

Comment: It's about the resolution/aspect ratio of your game. The black stripes are only here to compensate the unused parts of the screen, if you run your game on a screen with the same resolution as you set your game to be then the black stripes won't appear.

Comment: @FastBanana Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to extend the image to the full screen so that black stripes disappear?

Comment: If you set the resolution of your game to be the same as your screen as I said, the black striped will disappear when you build it (or if you use the editor in full-size). Send a screenshot of your project and I'll circle in red what you need to change.

Comment: @FastBanana Thanks for your help, but I have already solved this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved the change aspect when starting the game.